# Asynchronous classes and its features

Tags: java

Newbie in programming, I am trying to understand **Asynchronous** classes and the benefits. What features can be included in a class that supports such operations? With example too

Comment: There are quite a few "asynchronous classes" in Java and related libraries. It would be helpful if you asked a *specific* question, or if you simply Googled "java asynchronous examples" - you'd probably get more help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit is that your program do multiple things at the same time, instead of waiting for one thing to finish before doing the next.

Simple example: You want to show some information from twitter and facebook. Getting that information typically takes quite some time. So instead of waiting for twitter and then waiting for facebook, you can query both at the same time and get alerted when the information is available. This halves the time your user has to wait.